# Impossible to integrate adjust using GTM or Firebase

Tags: android, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

Google implemented Firebase & Google Tag Manager (GTM) API.

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/

There are possible to integrate the different tracking systems like "adjust":

https://www.adjust.com/

using Firebase or GTM.  In our company we want to use one tracking tool for all the tracking stuff, but for now looks it is impossible to use the new Firebase for that purpose. The question is how can i simply send events to adjust using Firebase (or maybe GTM)?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to send events to multiple supported vendors using GTM + Firebase. The [dev docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/) you linked to contains instructions on how to integrate with GTM.

While a large number of tag vendors require no additional integration beyond configuring the tag in GTM, adjust currently requires integration with their SDK as well. You will still be able to leverage all the [features](https://www.google.com/analytics/tag-manager/features/) of GTM, but will need to start a session with adjust before they begin accepting events.